# application of linearity of expectation

Tags: probability

Let $X$ and $Y$ be two discrete random variables such that $Y=X+a$. what is the mean of $Y$, $\mu_y$ with respect to $\mu_x$, the mean of $X$? Why does this make sense?

$Y=X+a$

$E(Y)=E(X+a)=E(X)+E(a)=E(x)+a$

I'm just a little confused on the "why does this make sense" part. Is the correct answer: this makes sense because of the linearity of expectation?

Comment: Seems like one of those questions where the asker wants to hear or read something that is so obvious to us that we don't even know how to put it in words. Try a concrete example and see if that gets you some points.

Answer (score 1):

I agree that the phrasing of the question is a little odd, but I reckon that they're probably looking for an intuitive explanation such as "because $a$ shifts the probability distribution of $X$, and so we would expect the mean of $Y$ to be the shifted mean of $X$". Or something along those lines.